# which way of using query will be efficient?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

i have two tables hsc,sslc
hsc:

```
id         name           class   section
1          karna            1        a
2          bavi             2        b
3          chidu            3        c
```

sslc

```
id         name           class    section
1          ram             11        a2
2          sam             11        b1
3          guna            14        c2
```

note:class which is present in hcs wont be there in sslc.
i should pass only  id and class as a condition to get the result using php but i wont pass the table name.so i am using using union query

```
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$class=$_REQUEST['class'];

$sql="select t1.* (select id,name,class,section from hsc union select  id,name,class,section from sslc)t1 where id=$id and class=$class;"//this runs successfully 
$StudentArray = $Cobj->union($sql);
```

OR

```
$sql="select * from hsc where id=$id and class=$class;"
$StudentArray = $Cobj->union($sql);
if(count($StudentArray)>0){
$table="hsc";}
else{
$table="sslc";}
$sql="select * from $table where id=$id and class=$class";
$StudentArray = $Cobj->union($sql);
```

both query result the same output . but will is an effective way?

Comment: First one is effective way

Comment: @Rahautos :can please say how and why?

Comment: The first one is probably more effective since you let the SQL server do all the optimisation work and you only query once (less interaction with php). But you should probably be using `union all` in the query, since the standard `union` will implicitly throw in a `distinct` clause which might slow things down again.

Comment: because in first case you execute one MySQL query .@VigneswaranS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First one is effective way** 
A single call will always be faster than several calls for the same data.Simply the network turn around and latency alone is a component, but also the start up and tear down of the SQL processing will have some impact.